# How to sole this for n?

Tags: matrices, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations

I started with a hard and unsuccessful way by putting the coefficcients into the matix. I need to solve the system of equation for any natural number n.

[system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYC7b.jpg)

Comment: in the other queastion. Problems with internet. Please, can someone delete this.